# save pointer object to system and load it in c++(not c)

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I am trying to create a python object in c++ and put it in a file to be used by another program. the problem I am facing that PyObject is a pointer and I don't know how to save a pointer to a file and reload it later. I have tried multiple solutions but nothing works for me, boost for example.

```
func = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "create_and_train");
pValue = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(func, PyUnicode_FromString(file_path.c_str()), PyLong_FromLong(size), NULL);
    //return feature_values, training_set
if (pValue != NULL)
{

    PyObject *object = PyTuple_GetItem(pValue, 0);

}
```

I want to save object pointer to a file and load it later.
Could any one help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps go through the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module? Of perhaps the Python C API have some functions to serialize/deserialize objects?

Comment: You cannot save a pointer to a file. You can save information about the object being pointed to so that you can recreate that object later. You can then get a pointer to that object in various ways. Is that what you want?

Comment: the problem is that the Pyobject has pointer variables too and the they point to other pointers. So it is difficult to create the object again.

Comment: One issue is that the O.S. may load your program at a different address each invocation, including data addresses.  When you store the address, it could be from "group 1" memory area and when the program is reloaded into "group 3", all the stored pointers are to locations in "group 1", which another program could be using.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are basically addresses of memory. Since they are dynamically allocated (meaning where ever there is space in the memory when you plan on executing it). This means that unless you are guaranteed that the location will not change whatsoever, you cant use a saved pointer.

One option is to copy the object's memory footprint to the file in binary. This means that you can load the whole object from the file at once at runtime. But be careful because if the object has pointers, it might not work properly because of the reason I stated before.

Saving the object's memory footprint is pretty simple,

```cpp
std::ofstream file("sim.bin", std::ios::binary);
if (!file.is_open()) return;    // Bail if failed.

// Dummy object as an example.
struct DummyObject { int x = 100; };

DummyObject obj;
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj), sizeof(DummyObject));
file.close();
```

And when loading the content,

```cpp
std::ifstream iFile("sim.bin", std::ios::binary);
if (!iFile.is_open()) return;   // Bail if failed.

DummyObject iobj;
iFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&iobj), sizeof(DummyObject));
iFile.close();
```

Now if that `DummyObject` had a pointer to some other thing, then we need to copy the content of that data to the file too. It'll slightly complicate things.

Comment: thanks for your response. the problem is that Pyobject pointer has the structur:
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject; 

moreover, ob_type inside it has the structur :

typedef struct _typeobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    const char *tp_name; 
    Py_ssize_t tp_basicsize, tp_itemsize;
   ...

So is it possible to get this pointer using your idea?

Comment: @omar but still if you know the sizes of those members, you can work something out...

Comment: I will try to save the object in python. It is complicated in c++. Thanks for the response

Comment: @omar Yup sure. Have a great day!